# How to run MATLAB in background

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran, interop

I have 2 programs:

1. A Fortran program that does a lot of calculations using intel compiler and Visual studio 2013, Windows 10. It generates a dataintomatlab.dat file as an input for the MATLAB program and receives a dataoutmatlab.dat file from MATLAB.
2. A MATLAB m.file which loads dataintomatlab.dat and save data as dataoutmatlab.dat as an input for the Fortran program.

The following code is used to link the Fortran program with MATLAB:

```
result_matlab = SYSTEMQQ("C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\matlab.exe" -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "my_mfile")
```

However, this is not efficient for large computations, because the MATLAB program has to be initiated and closed at each timestep, which takes a lot of time.

Is there any way to run MATLAB in the background without initiation and shut down every time and only make MATLAB do its work when it detects the dataintomatlab.dat is updated? Or is there a better solution to link the Fortran program with MATLAB?

Comment: You can use MATLAB's `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes to files (and respond accordingly). See `doc use .net events` in MATLAB

Comment: You could also compile the MATLAB code with `mcc` and link it to the fortran to make an executable -- then the MRC will only have to be loaded once at the start of the program.

Comment: Or you could do it the other way around, call your Fortran code from Matlab. You could even save time on the file exchanges if you use Mex functions.