# How to run multiple MATLAB tasks?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran

I linked a Fortran project with MATLAB to achieve the data exchange.

The Fortran subroutine is running on the Visual Studio 2010, win10. The version of MATLAB is R2019a.

Following code in the Fortran subroutine is used to call and run MATLAB with a simple window:

```
result_matlab = SYSTEMQQ("C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\matlab.exe" -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "my_mfile")
```

In order to do parameter analysis, two Fortran projects are built. However, if the first project is running, the second one can only open its own MATLAB window but with an error message. It seems like multiple MATLAB tasks can't work at the same time in this way.

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should merge this question with your previous one [How to run MATLAB in background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61500980/3460361) as they are very close and trying to solve the same overall problem. For example the comment you had on your first question (_check file change_) would be relvant for this one as well.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @PetrH, the problem seems to be solved after I put these two Fortran projects under different directories.